# When TestNG suite is executed, older versions of test class are being used

Tags: java, eclipse, git, testng

I have diffrent class for every test case. And when i change code and run that test suite, older version of code is being used.

For example:

**Old code**

```
logger.info("Older code");
```

**New code:**

```
logger.info("New code");
```

And when i run test suite, logger prints out "Older code" message.

Also what i noticed is that. On local Maven project this problem doesn't occur, but on git project it does occur.

Comment: Sounds like a dependency problem in your build system. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Answer (score 0):

You need commit your changes and push to remote repository.

Run in console (in your project folder)

- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Some changes"`
- `git push origin %branch_name%`